# Show that if $\{s_{n_k}\}_k$ converges to $L$, then $\{s_n\}_n$ converges to $L$.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Suppose a sequence $\{s_n\}_n$ is monotone increasing, consider any of its subsequences $\{s_{n_k}\}_k$. Show that if $\{s_{n_k}\}_k$ converges to $L$, then $\{s_n\}_n$ converges to $L$.

So I tried this problem and I was wondering if I did it correctly. My problem is that I'm unsure about the part where I say $s_n \leq s_{n_{k'}}$. Any corrections would be appreciated, thanks!

$|s_n - L| = |s_n - s_{n_k} + s_{n_k} - L| \leq |s_n - s_{n_k}| + |s_{n_k} - L|$

First note that since $\{s_{n_k}\}_k$ converges to $L$, we have that for all $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}^+$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ such that if $n_k \geq k \geq N$, then $|s_{n_k} - L| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Since $\{s_{n_k}\}_k$ is a subsequence of the monotone increasing sequence $\{s_n\}_n$, it follows that there exists $k'\in\mathbb{N}^+$ such that $n_{k'} \geq k' \geq n$, which implies $s_n \leq s_{n_{k'}}$ - because $\{s_{n_k}\}_k$ is increasing.

Subtracting by $s_{n_k}$ yields the following inequality:
\begin{equation*}
s_n - s_{n_k} \leq s_{n_{k'}} - s_{n_k}
\end{equation*}
and finally:
\begin{equation*}
|s_n - s_{n_k}| \leq |s_{n_{k'}} - s_{n_k}|.
\end{equation*}
But we know that $\{s_{n_k}\}_k$ is convergent, and thus Cauchy. So we can conclude that for all $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+$, there exists an natural number $N'$, for all natural numbers $n_{k'},n_k$ such that if $n_{k'},n_k\geq k',k\geq N'$, then $|s_{n_{k'}} - s_{n_k}| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Coupled with (i) we get that $|s_n - s_{n_k}| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.
\begin{equation*}
|s_n - L| \leq |s_n - s_{n_k}| + |s_{n_k} - L| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon.
\end{equation*}
$\{s_n\}_n$ converges to $L$.

Comment: Your proof looks fine to me. If you want, I think a much shorter proof can be obtained indirectly in the following way: we only need to show $s_n$ is bounded because it is then convergent and all subsequences converge to the same value. If $s_n$ is not bounded, it must diverge to $+\infty$ since it is a monotonic increasing sequence which means it has no convergent subsequences (hence a contradiction).

Comment: Right? I figured that every term of the sequence has a term in the subsequence that's bigger than it.